# How do I test or debug my migration scripts in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, migration, rake

I am current developing a big migration script, where I need to do the following:

1- Create new columns in table_1

2- Copy the values form table_2 to the new columns created in table_1

3- Delete table_2

I developed the up and down methods for this migration. My problem is that step 2 is just not copying my data correctly I need to be able to test/debug my code as it runs.

If there is a way please let me know. I am currently using Rails 2.3.8 but If there is a way for Rails 3 or 3.1 also please let me know.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug your data migration, you can use the `ruby-debug` gem and insert a breakpoint in the migration code:

```
require 'ruby-debug'; debugger
```

Then run the rake task:

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=whatever_version_number_your_migration_has
```

[Quick ruby-debug tutorial here.](http://pivotallabs.com/ruby-debug-in-30-seconds-we-don-t-need-no-stinkin-gui/)

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for noticing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating data in migrations is not a good idea. They should be used only to edit database structure. But you can always rename existing table, it`s columns and add new columns to it or remove some of them. List of available actions that can be performed on database via migrations can be found at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html